Getting isShowFullScreen: isShowFullScreen, static AdvanceInvitationState fromSignalingPluginInvitationUserState, Target kernel_snapshot failed: Excep
I was trying to integrate zegoCloud 1 to 1 video call in flutter linux and got this error while compiling the code
this is debug logs
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] Download native dependency
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] Native version: 3.17.0.40905
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] The specified version SDK (3.17.0.40905) already exists!
[ZEGO][PLUGIN] Copy the windows common code to the Linux platform.
ERROR: ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_uikit_prebuilt_call-4.9.0/lib/src/invitation/callkit/callkit_incoming_wrapper.dart:105:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isShowFullScreen'.
ERROR:       isShowFullScreen: isShowFullScreen,
ERROR:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_callkit_incoming_yoer-2.0.4+1/lib/entities/android_params.dart:8:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
ERROR:   const AndroidParams({
ERROR:         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_uikit-2.22.2/lib/src/plugins/signaling/impl/core/advance_invitation_data.dart:15:33: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'AdvanceInvitationState' doesn't allow null.
ERROR:  - 'AdvanceInvitationState' is from 'package:zego_uikit/src/plugins/signaling/impl/core/defines.dart' ('../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zego_uikit-2.22.2/lib/src/plugins/signaling/impl/core/defines.dart').
ERROR:   static AdvanceInvitationState fromSignalingPluginInvitationUserState(
ERROR:                                 ^
ERROR: Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
Exception: Build process failed

This is my pubspec.yaml dependencies
dependencies: 
    flutter: 
        sdk: flutter 
        cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 
        zego_uikit_prebuilt_call: ^4.9.0

default code from zegocloud prebuilt call kit
class CallPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CallPage({Key? key, required this.callID}) : super(key: key);
  final String callID;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCall(
      appID: Utils
          .appId, // Fill in the appID that you get from ZEGOCLOUD Admin Console.
      appSign: Utils
          .appSign, // Fill in the appSign that you get from ZEGOCLOUD Admin Console.
      userID: 'Sheikh_Umaid',
      userName: 'Sheikh Umaid',
      callID: callID,
      // You can also use groupVideo/groupVoice/oneOnOneVoice to make more types of calls.
      config: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVideoCall(),
    );
  }
}

i tried every version of the zegocloud to get work done in flutter web and flutter linux
tried code from ai
watched videos from youtube
read documentation
but nothing  worked
